# Create PDF from base64 in Perl

Tags: perl, pdf, base64

I get pdfdata from API (GLS carrier) encoded in base64 and I have to decode it and create pdf file from it.

This is my code:

```
my $decoded= MIME::Base64::decode_base64($xml_parsed->{'SOAP-ENV:Body'}->{'ns1:printlabelResponse'}->{'return'}->{'pdfdata'});

open(HND,'>'.$tom::P.'/_data/gls.pdf');
binmode HND;
print HND $decoded;
close (HND);
```

There is valid `base64` code in `$xml_parsed->{'SOAP-ENV:Body'}->{'ns1:printlabelResponse'}->{'return'}->{'pdfdata'}`, but if I write it into file, then Chrome says that pdf file is corrupted during opening.

Decoded string looks like:

```
$VAR1 = 'Óy{ãfï';
```

Chunk of base64:

```
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
```

Comment: Should use `open(my $HND, '>:raw', $tom::P.'/_data/gls.pdf') or die $!;`. That would have an effect on a Windows machine, but not likely on a unix machine. Otherwise, looks right from the info provided.

Comment: Could you maybe provide the first 20 or so characters of `$xml_parsed->{'SOAP-ENV:Body'}->{'ns1:printlabelResponse'}->{'return'}->{'pdfdata'}`?

Comment: @ikegami It works!! thanks :)

Comment: `:raw` prevents LF from being turned to CRLF. It will also override other things like `use open` and `PERLIO` env var.

Comment: @ikegami if you want you can post this as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prints bytes to a file without them getting mangled, open the file in "binary" mode.

```
open(my $fh, '>:raw', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");
```

(You can also do it after the fact using `binmode($fh)` or `binmode($fh, ':raw')`.)

This prevents the `:crlf` layer (which performs CR↔CRLF translation) from being added on Windows, this overrides the default encoding layer set via `use open`, etc.